# Ubuntu networking issue on OCI

Tags: networking, 20.04, cloud, oracle

I an using Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle Cloud (OCI), and struggling with accessing my web server from another host in the same subnet. Remote SSH works, ping/traceroute works, only having troubles with port `8080` on `TCP`.

From locally, I can access the web server on the subnet IP (it is bound to `0.0.0.0`):

[image: Accessing port 8080 locally]

Firewall is disabled:

[image: Firewall disabled]

Routing table seems to be OK (both instances have the same RT):

[image: Routing table]

From a remote host on the same subnet it fails with `No route to host`.

[image: Failing from the same subnet]

Considering the network, everything seems to be correct, I set up an everything-to-everywhere rule in OCI for this subnet. My gut feeling is that there's something on Ubuntu side I don't know about. Something must be enabled to be able to open a custom port.

Feel free to ask, I'm fighting this issue for a while.

Comment: Are you using UFW on Ubuntu and if so the port is open.

Comment: @David `ufw` is disabled. I tried also with `ufw` on, and adding an allow rule for TCP/8080, but did not work either.

Comment: I have the same issue on the other web server, and also from the load balancer (that's the most painful :D )

Answer (score 0):

For the records: the issue was with the `iptables`. After I enabled the needed ports, the instance is reachable from outside. The firewall was disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution that worked for me:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
sudo netfilter-persistent save
```